# Nginx location to index certain html file

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

```
// conf
server {
    listen 80;

    location /x {
        root /templates;
        index x.html;
    }
     location / {
        root /templates;
        index index.html;
    }
}
//
```

```
// Folder 
tempalets
| - index.html
| - x.html
```

I go to url `domain.com`, it's will show `index.html`

But, I go to url `domain.com/x`, it's will show `404 Not Found`.

And, I try `domain.com/x.html`, it's will show x.html.

Why url `domain.com/x` doen't show x.html?

How could I go to url `domain.com/x` and show x.html?

I don't want that `.html` in the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Alternative 1:**

Use [try_files](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files). Below it concatenates the extension (.html), so when requesting `/x` it first checks if the file `/templates/x.html` exists, then `/templates/x`, otherwise it `404s`.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        root /templates;
        try_files $uri.html $uri =404;
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

---

**Alternative 2:**

Upload the HTML files without the extension and set the [default_type](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#default_type) (MIME) to `text/html`.

```
default_type 'text/html';
```

https://blog.uidrafter.com/pretty-routes-for-static-html